# Add to Chart operation failed

Tags: pine-script

[image]

showing this line

```
Add to Chart operation failed, reason: Script could not be translated from: |B|BcB Ratio input(50,title=
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)